# Getting parameters and return value of lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have an interface which is

```
public static interface MyClass{
    public boolean doSomething(boolean a, boolean b);
}
```

I then instantiate  a variable

```
MyClass a = (boolean x, boolean y) -> x && y;
```

Now my question is that if I want to get the parameters x and y and the return value, how would I go about doing that? The reason I want to get the parameters is because I want to serialize so that I am able to do a `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` with them.

Not sure if my question fully makes sense. I haven't worked with lambda too much so any sort of guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Adding On: OK so MyClass a is instantiated in another class, let's call it `ParentClass`. So now I have

```
MyClass a = (x, y) -> x && y;
    ParentClass b = new ParentClass();
    b.setMyClass(a);
```

Now in the main class that I am working in, I get passed `ParentClass b`. So I take it and do
    MyClass c = b.getMyClass;
Which if I understand correctly is a reference to `(x, y) -> x && y;`. Now the question is, how do I get the values of the parameters and return value so that I can serialize it. Also MyClass will not always be `(x,y) -> x && y`, it could be anything i.e

```
MyClass a = (x, y) -> x || y;
MyClass a = (x, y) -> x^y;
MyClass a = (x, y) -> true;
```

I'm not allowed to modify MyClass or ParentClass. Which is why I was trying to get the parameters passed and the return value so that I could serialize those and send them through.

Comment: You're passing x and y, how could you not know their value?

Comment: All I'm getting is the variable a. I don't have direct access to x and y nor to the return value.

Comment: how can you not have access?

Comment: If you want to serialize, make your interface `extends Serializable`.

Comment: There is no x or y then. There's a function which could be called.  You could call `a.doSomething(true, true)` and then call `a.doSomething(false, false)` - what are x and y then?

Comment: The type is inferred -- you know `x` and `y` are boolean, so `x && y` can be nothing other than boolean so `a` must be boolean, or at least constructable from a boolean.

Comment: If all you have is a `MyClass` object, then you don't have the parameter values yet; all you have is a functional interface `a` that hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: You would call `boolean result = a.doSomething(x, y);` You have to supply `x` and `y`, so you should know what they are. The answer will be in `result`.

Comment: You don't need to know the arguments or return value of a lambda to serialize it. Just extend `Serializable` and you will be able to serlialize the `a` variable in `ParentClass`.

Comment: @sprinter I'm not able to modify ParentClass.

Comment: You don't have to modify `ParentClass`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the lambda syntax is, simply, a way to describe the behaviour of a method without giving it a name.

e.g. `(Type1 arg1, Type2 arg2, ...) -> <expression>`
defines a function looking something like this:

```
public TypeOfExpression anonymousMethod(Type1 arg1, Type2 arg2, ...) {
    ...
    return <expression>;
}
```

Look on the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for more info on lambdas.

In fact the lambda expression `(boolean x, boolean y) -> x && y` (when given type `MyClass` as you define it) is nothing but syntactic sugar for the following:

```
new MyClass() {
    public boolean doSomething(boolean x, boolean y) {
        return x && y;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that gives some clarity into what lambdas are representing in Java.

In technical terms, the interface definition you gave defines a ['function type'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_type). In Java, any interface which has only a single method is called 'functional', and can be used, instead of as an interface, as the type of a lambda expression of the same type as the single method in the interface.

This decision was presumably made because if an interface has only one method, all that is needed to specify it is the *behaviour* of that method, which can be far more concisely written in the lambda notation, as demonstrated above.

So, the lambda expression is nothing but an instance of your interface - in particular, it has no fields, but defines a method behaviour. I think you are assuming instead that it encapsulates a pair of inputs and their output result. If this is what you need, you might be looking for something more like a pair type with a built in operation (like `&&` in this case).

EDIT: on serializability.

It's apparent that you require serialization of an unknown function of MyClass type. If `MyClass` extends `Serializable`, you should be able to cast appropriately and serialize. If you're not in control of `MyClass`, so can't ensure this, the following ad hoc observation may help.

If the method in `MyClass` is indeed of the type shown here `(boolean, boolean) -> boolean`, there are a small enough number of cases to consider that you can manually serialize.

The number of 'possible' (total) functions of type `A -> B`, for finite-sized types `A` and `B` is `|B|`^`|A|` (size of `B` to the power size of `A`). This is because, counting the possible functions, for each input of type `A` there are `|B|` possible outputs the function could give.

Also, the size of the pair type `(A, B)` is `|A|`*`|B|`.

In our case, we have `(boolean, boolean) -> boolean`. But `boolean` is only of size 2! So `(boolean, boolean)` is of size 4, and `(boolean, boolean) -> boolean` is of size 2^4 = 16.

How do we work out which of these 16 functions we have on our hands? Simply enumerate through the possible inputs (only 4 to do). Then we can record the four outputs in variables something like this (where `a` will be our unknown function.)

```
boolean ttout = a(true, true);
boolean tfout = a(true, false);
boolean ftout = a(false, true);
boolean ffout = a(false, false);
```

Then we can merrily serialize these four values. :)

Further, if we are deserializing and obtain the four values (`ttout`, `tfout`...) we can reconstruct the function something like this:

```
a = (boolean x, boolean y) -> {
    if (x) {
        if (y) return ttout;
        else return tfout;
    } else {
        if (y) return ftout;
        else return ffout;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I'm starting to understand the syntax a lot more (been doing a lot of reading online) and your conversion makes a lot of sense too. But my initial problem still remains. I have `MyClass a = (x, y) -> (some return value)`. This is instantiated in another class and I am only given the variable a. How can I serialize that variable?

Comment: If serializing the interface/lambda expression is all you require, it looks like people have suggested good things already. It will be necessary that `MyClass` extends `Serializable`, though: if you are expecting an unknown instance of `MyClass`, you can't assume it'll be serializable if not.

Comment: If you're not in control of the definition of `MyClass` (so can't ensure it's serializable), one thing that occurs to me is that, if indeed all instances operate on (primitive) boolean inputs, there are actually only four inputs to consider - you could manually serialize any possible binary operation on booleans in as little as four bits! (One for result of input (true, true), one for (true, false).....)

Comment: Yeah but how will I know which one it was that was originally passed into the variable `a`? It could be any of the four and there could be different return values, depending on what the user inputs.

Comment: Edit is now done; I explain and demonstrate an ad hoc way to serialize binary operators over primitive booleans. The manner in which you actually serialize the variables I obtain in the example is up to you - a literal four-bit value would be enough, but it might just be easier to group them as four values of a small array or something.

Comment: We serialize all the possibilities but how do we know which one was originally passed to the function? i.e how do we compare to the original return value?

Comment: I refer you to the first part of my answer and the other answers on this question. :) it seems there's still a misunderstanding of what a lambda is. It's nothing but a function; in particular, it doesn't retain any information about what inputs it's been called with and what the results were. In fact, we can (and do, often!) have functions which are never called at all, so it makes no sense to ask what argument was 'originally passed to the function': when asking about a function, we care about how it behaves, not how it may or may not have been used in the past.

Comment: Of course, my ad hoc example of how to manually serialize arbitrary binary operators on booleans makes several 'pure functional' assumptions: the function is deterministic (its result does not depend on chance, or the time of day, or the weather...) and total (there are no inputs for which its output is undefined, represented in Java probably by either an exception or an infinite loop). For operations on primitive booleans these assumptions seem reasonable.

Comment: what is type of a?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are misunderstanding how lambda expressions work. Your question implies that you are expecting to create your `a` object and then serialize it and in the process somehow record the values of `x` and `y`. Have I understood you correctly?

If so then this is fundamentally not how lambdas work. They are not an object containing state in the ordinary sense. Rather think of them as a bit of executable code that you can pass around that can be applied to a set of values whenever you want (I suspect I'll be hammered in the comments for that overly simplistic explanation!).

You can serialize lambdas but in that case you are serializing the operation represented by the lambda, not the values passed to it in any given invocation.

If you want implementations of the `MyClass` interface to be serializable then it needs to extend `Serializable`. It should look as follows:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyClass extends Serializable {
    boolean doSomething(boolean a, boolean b);
}
```

If you can't modify `MyClass` then you can still cast a `MyClass` object to `Serializable`:

```
Serializable a = (Serializable & MyClass)(a, b) -> a || b;
```

Or if you are using the value from a `ParentClass`:

```
Serializable a = (Serializable)b.getMyClass();
```

You should then be able to serialize `a`.

Just remember when you deserialize that you need to cast back to `MyClass` so that you can use it. It will look something like:

```
MyClass b = (Serializable & MyClass)objectInStream.readObject();
b.doSomething(true, false);
```

Comment: OK that makes sense...how can I go about serializing a lambda though? I have little to no experience in lambdas, let alone understanding how to serialize it.

Comment: I've looked at that post but don't understand how to implement it in my function. I do `MyClass a = (MyClass & Serializable) b.getMyClass();` but when I go to write it to the outputstream, I get Lambda cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

Comment: You need to define the `MyClass` interface as extending `Serializable`.

Comment: I would, but I'm not allowed to modify `MyClass` or `ParentClass`. Which is why I was trying to get the parameters passed and the return value so that I could serialize those and send them through. I appreciate the help. Thanks. Sorry for being difficult

Comment: That would have been useful information to have in the original question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95093/discussion-between-user2989280-and-sprinter).

Answer (score 1):

If you want `a` itself to be serializable, you can write `a = (MyClass & Serializable) (boolean x, boolean y) -> x && y`.

There is no `x` or `y` just from the definition of `a`, though: those only exist when `a` is actually invoked.